# MySQL Statement without a JOIN

Tags: mysql, join, where-clause

I have a MySQL table I am trying to query articles_data and I don't want to do any joins to other tables.

It has rows:

```
article_id  doc_type  doc_type_id
1           1         2
1           2         1
2           1         2
3           1         2
3           2         1
```

I am trying to write a query which would return where `doc_type` is 1 and `doc_type_id` is 2 AND where it has another row for the same `article_id` where `doc_type` is 2 and `doc_type_id` is 1 so in the above example I am trying to return `article_id` 1 and 3.

Any ideas how I would would write an SQL query to do this?

Comment: You can probably use a subquery, but the easiest is to use a JOIN. Any particular reason you want to avoid a JOIN?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to join to other tables, but you could do it with a self join

This is from the top of my head, you might need to tweak the syntax

```
select distinct article_id
from articles_data a
join articles_data b on b.articles_id = a.articles_id
where a.doc_type = 1 and a.doc_type_id = 2
and b.doc_type = 2 and b.doc_type_id = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct article_id
from articles_data ad
where 
    doc_type = 1 and 
    doc_type_id = 2 and
    article_id in (
        select article_id 
        from articles_data
        where 
            article_id = ad.article_id and 
            doc_type = 2 and 
            doc_type_id = 1
    )
```

Comment: That will return all three article_id values, won't it?

Comment: @karolis: The `article_id = ad.article_id and ` should be removed.

Comment: @ypercube This is not needed, but with this the query will be faster. In any case I think it's a homework exercise, so any decision is good.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT article_id
FROM article_data
WHERE (doc_type = 1 AND doc_type_id = 2)
   OR (doc_type = 2 AND doc_type_id = 1)
GROUP BY article_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT doc_type) = 2 AND COUNT (DISTINCT doc_type_id) = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT article_id
FROM article_data ad
WHERE doc_type = 1
  AND doc_type_id = 2
  AND EXISTS
    ( SELECT *
      FROM article_data ad2
      WHERE ad2.doc_type = 2
        AND ad2.doc_type_id = 1
        AND ad2.article_id = ad.article_id
    )
```